# Android App Crashing on Android 8.0 (Google Pixel XL)

Tags: java, android, exception, android-studio-2.2, android-8.0-oreo

My App was working fine but since Android Oreo has come to Google Pixel XL it keeps Crashing 
following is the Exception stack-trace

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "boolean android.app.job.JobServiceEngine.onStartJob(android.app.job.JobParameters)"
>          at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:108)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Need more context to understand this problem, for example what's the targetSdk

Comment: patrick-iv 
 minSdkVersion 16
 targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: Try bumping your targetSdk to 26 (Android 0)

Comment: its working on 8.0 already but this issue is only occurs in Google Pixel XL

Answer (score 0):

If proguard is enabled for your application, it might be the case where the static inner classes are getting removed. You can add properties in proguard to retain the inner class that implements JobServiceEngine using -keep command.

For ex, if the class that implements the JobServiceEngine is JobServiceEngineImpl which is a static inner class of JobIntentService, add

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.JobIntentService$* {
    *
}
```